# jquerymobile ios5 positioning elements in div[data-role=content

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios5

Has anyone noticed their elements not sitting correctly in ios5 in the content area? My content block seems to start above the header on same pages and on other pages the elements inside my content block start too far down.

Wasn't expecting this, can't see anything mentioned on the web, thought I might ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, but I did have issues in the past with malformed tags or divs that were setting too much margin/padding and would cause the content not to "sit right".

I would suggest loading the page in GoogleChrome and using the css debugger to see if anything is out of bounds...

Hope this helps